# What's the best way to test if a value exists in an sqlite table?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

First question here, so please don't whack me if i do something dumb!

I'm creating a login system including registration etc. and with the registration i need to test 3 things to see if they are already in use.

My initial test code looks something like this:

```
$IDq = $userdbc->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '$uID'");
$IDq->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$IDf = $IDq->fetch();
if($IDf['userID']){
    echo '<p>ID exists</p>';
}
else{
    echo '<p>ID does not exist?</p>';
}
```

I'm going to need to test for possible duplicate email and display names.. i'm sure there must be a better way to go about this?

Or am i really going to have to repeat the process 3 times to test for each item?

This is my first real venture using a database solution.. Any usefull input is very much appreciated - thanks in advance!

EDIT: I do need to test each value individually so that i can rebuild the registration form with appropriate error message's stating exactly what needs to be changed. Sorry i should have been more specific.

---

EDIT: **The Solution** - thankyou Shakti Singh, and everyone else for the help.

The function (using prepared statement with named placeholder):

```
function item_exists($dbc, $col, $val){
    $query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $col = :val");
    $query->execute(array(':val' => $val));
    $fetch = $query->fetch();
    if($fetch[$col]){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

How i'm using it within my registration validation function:

```
$userdbc = new PDO('sqlite:db/users.s3');

if(item_exists($userdbc, 'userID', $_POST['id'])){
    $valid = false;
    array_push($sub['e'], 'User ID is not available.');
}
if(item_exists($userdbc, 'userEmail', $_POST['email'])){
    $valid = false;
    array_push($sub['e'], 'Email Address is already in use.');
}
if(item_exists($userdbc, 'userName', $_POST['name'])){
    $valid = false;
    array_push($sub['e'], 'Display Name already taken.');
}
$userdbc = null;
```

---

EDIT: **Additional:**

As i am only testing one item, within the `item_exists()` function i substituted:

```
$query->execute(array(':val' => $val));
```

for:

```
$query->bindParam(':val', $val);
$query->execute();
```

..just because executing an array seemed kinda dumb to me as it only holds one key/value..

No idea what the actual difference might be, but hey its another option.

EDIT: **Additional-Additional:**

The function with all changes made:

```
function item_exists($dbc, $col, $val, $rn){
    // updated the prepare statement as per James Anderson's suggestion.
    $query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT COUNT($col) AS dupli FROM users WHERE $col = :val");
    $query->bindParam(':val', $val);
    $query->execute();
    $fetch = $query->fetch();
    // $fetch['dupli'] contains the number of matches found.
    // $fetch[0] should also work, but not tested.
    if($rn){ // if $rn = true, return the number of finds
        return $fetch['dupli'];
    }
    else{ // else we are just testing for a match so..
        if($fetch['dupli'] > 0){ // if we have one
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I just felt i should add this in case anyone else struggled like i did, always nice to have working examples - with comments too ^_~

I'm fairly sure this will be my last edit but meh.. never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not repeat the process 3 times to test for each item.

Just create a generic method or function, which will be called for each item you want to check and return true or false based on database values.

```
function item_exists($item_value,$item_type)
{
   $IDq = $userdbc->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $item_type= '$item_value'");
   $IDq->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $IDf = $IDq->fetch();
   if($IDf[$item_type])
   {
     return true;
   } 
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

And call function like this

```
if (item_exists($userID, 'userID') === true)
{
     echo 'user_id exists';
}

if (item_exists($emailID, 'email') === true)
{
     echo 'email exists';
}
```

This method will let you know what is duplicated. so that you can show as a message to end user.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for my case, thankyou very much Shakti Singh, i have incorporated it with a few adjustments (noteably its now using a prepared statement with named placeholders)

Comment: @Jason: your welcome, Please click on the right arrow sign in left to let visitors know that the issue has been solved.

Comment: the what in the where now? the green "tick"? "right" meaning correct i hope lol - sorry for the noobiness, only been lurking around here a few days ^_^

Answer (score 1):

They are three different tests so why not three SQLs?

You can and should change your "`select *`"  to a "`select count(*) as idcount`" as then the whole query can be satisfied by index access only.

If you really want to do it in one SQL then:

```
    Select sum(DUP_USER) as du, sum(DUP_NAME) as dn, Sum(DUP_EMAIL) as de 
from (
    Select Case when userId = '$Uid' then 1 Else 0 End AS DUP_USER
           Case when userName = '$uname' then 1 Else 0 End AS DUP_NAME
           Case when userEmail = '$uEmail' then 1 Else 0 End as DUP_EMAIL
    From users
     WHERE userID= '$uID' 
        OR userName = '$uName' 
        OR userEmail = '$uEmail' )
```

But honestly three separate SQLs are much more readable.

Comment: I didn't go for the all-in-one SQL but i did set about learning to understand it. So thankyou for the input :) i did however make a last update including your suggestion on `select count(*) as idcount` with a small variation - still testing things out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it thrice just add condition in the `WHERE` clause like

```
WHERE userID= '$uID' OR userName = '$uName' OR userEmail = '$uEmail'
```

So when doing this, if any one of the condition satisfies then you'll get a row, and then you'll know a duplicate entry exist

**EDIT**

For further reading on OR -  check [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) under the topic **OR optimizations**

Comment: But then he has no idea what is duplicated.

Comment: He just wants to know if a duplicate entry for any of the valuesexist right. And also if he wants he can check the row returned from this query, where he is checking one row for three conditions than searching the entire database thrice

Comment: This would work to an extent, but i really need to be able to test each item separately so that i can respond with appropriate error messages such as "Sorry this email is already in use" etc. I will amend my initial post.

Comment: So now you have the tow returned from this query, just have an `if` condition to check which value is equal : `if($IDf['userID'])==$uID echo 'UserId exists' `, and in a similar manner for email and ID. This will be much more optimized than, searching the db three times

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an OR statement:

```
$IDq = $userdbc->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '$uID' OR email='$email' OR displayName='$displayName'");
$IDq->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$IDf = $IDq->fetch();

echo ($IDf['userID'] == $uID) ? '<p>ID exists</p>' : '<p>ID does not exist?</p>';
echo ($IDf['email'] == $email) ? '<p>Email exists</p>' : '<p>Email does not exist?</p>';
echo ($IDf['displayName'] == $displayName) ? '<p>DisplayName exists</p>' : '<p>DisplayName does not exist?</p>';
```

I hope you're escaping the values before sending them to the database and just missed that part out in your post. Otherwise you're open to SQL injections

Comment: all user entered data gets processed where necessary before it goes near the database, and i also use named placeholders. Security isn't where i'm stuck, just learning how to access data properly is where im tripping up :)